# I have an administrator account, why can I not turn of the automatic installation (and reboot) of updates in windows server 2008 r2?

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-update

When I go to the control panel, the drop down to change the automatic updates configuration is disabled. It says I need administrator access, but I have without a doubt an admin account.

Why is this disabled so I cannot turn of the automatic installation (and reboot) of updates in windows server 2008 r2?

Does this mean that the only account that can change this setting is the original admin account (username: administrator)?

A windows update recently caused the server to fail to boot up after restart!

Comment: Is this a domain-connected machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this machine is connected to a domain, you are most likely under control of the Group Policy, which has been setup to not allow users to make changes to Automatic Updates, this may include administrators.

Comment: The same settings are also available through local policy, which would look the same.

Comment: DanBig is probably correct here.  Also running GPResult ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733160%28WS.10%29.aspx ) should tell you what all the policies/setting are.

Comment: Also, group policy overrides local policy. If that's the case, you're stuck with whatever update policy the domain administrator deems worthy.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not of much help but before I join the machine to the Domain I make sure I setup the Windows Update settings correctly according to our policy. Otherwise what you see happens.

I would loging onto the server as the Administrator account for that machine and make the required changes.

Answer (score 0):

Open Administrator Tools>>Group Policy Management.
Find the appropriate policy.
Computer Configuration>>Policies>>Window Components>>Windows Update

You should see settings set here that are overwriting your local settings.

Comment: I am in the process of obtaining the credentials for the "administrator" account - I'll check back as soon as I'm in and have taken a look. Thanks, Chris.